# CNAMEing a SRV domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, srv-record

I have two domain names: `example.com` and `example2.com`. `example.com` has a few SRV records to handle specific services, as well as an A record for a website. I would like `example2.com` to have a CNAME to `example.com`.

If I create this CNAME record, will `example2.com` also have all of the SRV records from `example.com`? If not, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `SRV` record should exist at a name like `_service._protocol.example.com.`.
Unless it was this specific name that you made into an alias, queries for this name would not be affected.

Also worth noting, a `CNAME` record is not allowed at the zone apex. A name cannot both be defined to be an alias of another name and have additional data of its own and the zone apex will always have at least `SOA` and `NS` records.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of a DNAME?

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/dname.html